# Move two windows together tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, binding, move

I have two types of windows: Main and Child. When I move main, all child windows must move also.
So I tried to write a method, but I am new to Tkinter so it is a bit hard. Isn't there a mehtod which Tkinter already provides? 
There are two errors which occure:

line 21, in move_me if second_window != None:
NameError: name 'second_window' is not defined

wm_geometry() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

''' import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import Tk
    from functools import partial
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import tkinter as tk

`````
root=Tk()

def second_window_X():
    global second_window
    second_window=Tk()
    label=Label(second_window, text='window')
    label.pack()

button=Button(root, text='second window', command=second_window_X)
button.pack()

def move_me(event):
    if second_window != None:
        x = root.winfo_x()
        y = root.winfo_y()
        second_window.geometry(x,y)
root.bind("<Configure>", move_me)

root.mainloop()````
`````

Is there someone who can give me an example how to link both windows togehter and make them move at the same time? And who can explain to me, why move me doesn't knows second_window even if i declared it as global?

Thank you very much already

Sorry for all the imports

Comment: When `move_me` is first called, `second_window` is not created yet.  And `second_window.geometry(x, y)` should be `second_window.geometry('+%s+%s' % (x, y))`.

Comment: You shouldn't have two instances of Tk. If you want a second window, it should use Toplevel instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in a comment, you shouldn't have two instances of Tk in an application. Your second window should be an instance of Toplevel.

The below code moves the second window when the first window is moved/resized.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

second_window = None

def second_window_X():
    global second_window
    second_window=Toplevel(root)
    label=Label(second_window, text='window')
    label.pack()

button=Button(root, text='second window', command=second_window_X,width=100)
button.pack()

def move_me(event):
    try:
        if second_window != None:
            x = root.winfo_x()
            y = root.winfo_y()
            second_window.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")
    except NameError:
        pass
root.bind("<Configure>", move_me)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried to put the function in to a more complex programm and now I have got the problem that its says _tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'info_y'. Do you know that error? I would really like to show that piece of code but I only got round about 300 chars left...

Comment: @Fi-cyber You should raise a new question for that issue. I have resolved your original question.